# What is the correct name for relation like things such as $\in$ and =

Tags: elementary-set-theory

= and $\in$ look like relations and you can sometimes treat them like they are.  However the domain and codomain of both is the class of all sets. Is there a term for this type of thing?

Comment: Both equality and "is an element of" are *binary* relations.

Comment: "Class relation", perhaps? You do have class functions (the ordinal successor function is one such, for instance).

Comment: They are relations in the general English sense, but not in the usual set theory sense. In formal logic / proof theory, they might be called connectives, but that's just syntax of a statement, not their meaning.

Comment: In "pure" set theory (i.e. set theory without *atoms* (objects that are not sets)) we can define the first one from the second.

Comment: However relations happen between elements of sets. “Is an element of” has a domain that includes all sets and therefore can’t be between sets,

Comment: Some seem to be missing the point... When we define relations in a course on elementary set theory, we generally do so as *subsets* of the cartesian product of two *sets*... yet these objects here, $\in$ and $=$, are used in broader contexts involving possibly *any* of the sets on either side.  If a universal set actually existed, it would feel like $=$ was a subset of the cartesian product of the universal set with itself... but such a thing is not a set and so it wouldn't fall under the "is a subset of the cartesian product of two sets" definition.

Comment: @JMoravitz - correct; they are binary **predicate symbols**.

Comment: See Kenneth Kunen, The Foundations of Mathematics (College, 2009), page 9: **Ch.1 Set Theory**: "We work in predicate logic with binary relations $=$ and $\in$."

Comment: And see Thomas Jech, [Set Theory (Springer, 2006)](https://books.google.it/books?id=CZb-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA161), page 161: **Models of Set theory**: "The language of set theory consists of one binary predicate symbol $\in$, and so models of set theory are given by its universe $M$ and a binary relation $E$
on $M$ that interprets $\in$. **Definition 12.6**. Let $M$ be a *class*, $E$ a binary relation on $M$ and let ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, use the shortest term you don't think will be misunderstood. I second @Arthur's suggestion: If you define *relation* too precisely (i.e. on sets) for that to be a legal description, go with *class relation*. (I prefer *binary class relation* over *class binary relation*, but neither is likely to be used often.) Having said that, @MauroALLEGRANZA noted such precision is skipped in Kunen 2009, and suggested calling them *predicate symbols*, which makes sense unless you want to emphasize that they're mathematical objects. For example in $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\in\mathord{\in}$ (I can't apologize enough for how horrible that looks!), the first $\in$ is a symbol for a binary predicate, but the second is a binary class relation.